# Allowing certain function call only if it is followed by another function

Tags: c++, function, macros, brackets, statements

I want to create a function that must be called with { } braces.  Similar
to if, while and for statements.  The reason for this is to prevent the operator from calling the function without adding the necessary code that follows.

```
#include <iostream>

/* function to run the test */
bool runTest()
{
    std::cout "PASS" << std::endl;
    return true;
}

/* function will print the passed chars */
void newTest(const char *functionName, const char *testName)
{
    std::cout << functionName << " " << testName;
}

int main(void)
{
    /* OPTION 1 */
    /* You can call it like this */
    newTest("runTest", "TestName");
        runTest();
    / * OR */
    newTest("runTest", "TestName");
    {
        runTest();
    }

    /* OPTION 2 */
    /* I want the operator to be required to do */
    newTest("runTest", "TestName")
    {
        runTest();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I want option 2 to be the correct usage.  Because with option 1 you could call that like:

```
newTest("runTest", "TestName");
newTest("otherTest", "TestName");
   runTest();
```

but you would not have the necessary call to runTest() that is related to the first calls output.

The output would be:

```
runTests TestName /*(NULL)*/
otherTest TestName PASS
```

This way of calling is just checking to make sure the operator called the test after the newTest() function.

Ideally if the operator was perfect he could call the functions properly.

```
newTest("runTest", "TestName");
    runTest();
newTest("otherTest", "TestName");
   runTest();
```

But i want to eliminate the error but automatically requiring the operator to call the function with {} following the call.

Comment: If you want a function to run user supplied code you should have your function take in a function/functor/lambda and run that inside your function.

Comment: That is great idea, I can't believe i didn't think of that lol. Ideally something like this would work  `newTest(runtests, "runTests", "TestName")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, those 'curly brackets' are called 'braces' - you may want to edit your question so people understand better.

unless someone changed it without telling me; C++ doesn't work this way.
Braces in this context are reserved explicitly for [the scope of keywords, function-definitions, and initializer lists](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope).

```
void Badger()
{ //this is fine, it's a function-definition
}
int main()
{
for(I =0; I < 5; I++)
   { //this is fine, for is a keyword.
   }
foo()
   { //This is not legal, foo must take it's perimeters within brackets, not braces.
   } 
}
```

If you wish a user to pass code to a function, you must do so using a [Function-pointer](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/function-pointers.html), the user then may pass a existing function, [or a lambda.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda)

```
void Foo(bool (Function_ptr*) ()) { };
bool Function_To_Pass() { } ;
int main()
{
    Foo(&Function_To_Pass);
    Foo([]()
    {
        //Code to run here
    });
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't suggest just using a function pointer.  I would make it generic and take any callable type.  Also note that lambdas that capture cannot be converted to a function pointer.

Comment: C++11 introduced list initialization, e.g. `std::vector<int> vec { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };`, but I see you've already edited your post to reflect that.

Comment: The only reason I was trying to use the braces was because I saw it's usage in other code and was trying to replicate a similar result.  I believe the way it was done in the other code with with macros.  I like both of the options you have given.  Like Nathan's comment i think this is the best way.

Comment: @TylerGajewski I'm glad I could help - Personally I dislike anything generic, I prefer very strict typing in all scenarios, but perhaps i'm a masochist.

Answer (score 0):

```
   #include <iostream>

/* function to run the test */
bool runTest()
{
    std::cout << " PASS" << std::endl;
    return true;
}

/* function will print the passed chars */
void newTest(bool (*function)(), const char *functionName, const char *testName)
{
    std::cout << functionName << " " << testName;
    function();
}

int main(void)
{
    newTest(runTest, "runTest", "TestName");

    return 0;
}
```

This will return the desired result based on @JohnBargman and @NathanOliver suggestions.

And Ideally what runTest() will do is allow operator to pass in arguments and the runTest function will do work with those arguments.  So i wanted the function call to create scope with the braces. like:

```
newTest("runTests", "TestName")
{
    int number = 1;
    runTests(number);
}
```

But I guess that if the operator is using this code he/she should know that he/she could use the braces to create scope. and thus it is not required.